# How to know if Contact exists like a number in android

Tags: android

I am using the below code to know if any contact exists with a number in android native contacts

```
public boolean contactExists(Context context, String number) {
            /// number is the phone number
            Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
            PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, 
            Uri.encode(number));
            String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = { PhoneLookup._ID, PhoneLookup.NUMBER, PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };
            Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri,mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);
            try {
               if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                  return true;
            }
            } finally {
            if (cur != null)
               cur.close();
            }
            return false;
            }
```

my problem is that if i get a number with country code added.

so,can i compare only last 7 numbers in my query

Answer (score 1):

You should probably look at the `PhoneNumbersUtils` class.

Comment: and then what? I wish I could use PhoneNumberUtils.compare, but I don't deal with the comparison itself, I have to pass a String with the phone number in some format to the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
String numberToCheck;
if (numberToCheck.endsWith(number)) {
  //do smth
}
```

This should do the job.